# Get access to $item->getNumberOfDownloadsUsed() function on Download.php

Tags: magento-1, downloadable, download, download-link, purchase-order

I need to get the number of downloads bought and used, that's two methods that are available on `$item` object. But I can't instance `$item` on the file that I'm working:

`app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php`

On this file, I need to retrieve the number of boughts and used of the download purchased.

I'm also trying to get the order ID or at least the link hash to identify that number of boughts/used downloads with the unique id of the purchase.

For example, I try this:

```
Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
            ->load($this->getOrderItem()->getOrder()->getId(), 'order_id');
```

But `$this->getOrderItem()` is not available on `Download.php` file. I was trying this:

```
Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_item_id', $this->getOrderItem()->getId());
```

But obviously `getOrderItem()` is unavailable.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Downloadable_Helper_Download::getOrderItem() in /[...]/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/Download.php on line 135

But I'm able to use the customer singleton to retrieve client data like this:

```
$cliente = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

So on this file I'm able to access others methods, but I'm unable to get the following details:

- Number of downloads bought
- Number of downloads used
- Order ID or Link hash ID.

So please, I'm requesting how to get the current order instance and / or the current link instance, on the `Download.php` related with the file downloading.

Thank you!